# Why my page is re-rendering(refreshing) when scrolling to the bottom in React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, page-refresh

i wanna ask something because i really  can't find why this is happening. Why my page is re-rendering(refreshing) when scrolling to the bottom? I mean its fetching more items like i want but it is updated with refresh , and i don't want that. This is the code:
https://pastebin.com/ESu7ijiy

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const event = window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        if ((isLoading && window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight - 2){
            setPage((oldPage) => {
                return oldPage + 1;
            });
         }
    });

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", event);
}, []);
```

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` in the `addEventListener`.

Comment: This doesn't fix it, but i found the solution. In the end i think i didn't explain the situation correct, the trouble wasn't refreshing(because i found that it doesn't), it was re-rendering part, i fix the problem with changing the structure of files

Answer (score 0):

Because inside your second useEffect you wrote this

```
setPage((oldPage) => {
      return oldPage + 1;
    });
  }
```

Here you're incrementing `page` by scrolling down.
And since in your first useEffect you passed `page` as second dependencies

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getPhotosFromInitUrl();
  }, [searchValue, page]);
```

first useEffect will call `getPhotosFromInitUrl()` every time page will change `page` inside your second useEffect

Comment: yes, exactly, and i think i somehow avoid that problem - i explained it in next answer, thank you for the feedback, helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - the trouble was in the structure of the files

```
<Container component="main" className="App">
  <SearchForm
    value={value}
    setValue={setValue}
    handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
  />
  <Box component="section" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
    {isLoading && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
    <Grid container spacing={5}>
      {photos.map((photo) => {
        return (
          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
            <SinglePhoto {...photo} />
          </Grid>
        );
      })}
    </Grid>
  </Box>
</Container>
```